# Calculating makespan among several machines

Tags: algorithm-analysis

I have a question about makespan calculation. I know that makespan formula is like this:

> Makespan = Time of completion of last job - Starting time of the first
>   job

but I can't figure out how we should use it for several machines. I have a load balancing algorithm that helps in processing of several independent jobs on 3 homogeneous machines. A central coordinator gathers the load on each machine (lead = number of tasks on each machine) and if there is an overloaded device, the coordinator will move some of its tasks to a less-loaded machine. By the way jobs are not consisted of small tasks and all the job should be done on a single machine. I want to calculate makespan for this algorithm.

Now in order to calculate makespan, should I calculate makespan for each machine separately

or

I should do this among all machines? I mean should I find the time of earliest job arrived to these machines and also find the time of last job among 3 machines and apply the above formula to them?

Comment: "I have 2 load balancing algorithms" Please add an accessible reference to the algorithms _in the question_. How to calculate makespan depends on how it is defined and used in those algorithms.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Doesn't makespan represent the duration of an algorithm? For example, the time between when the first task is arrived to one of processors and when the last task is finished on one of processors?

Comment: @Apass.Jack There is no reference to the mentioned algorithm since it's not published yet, but I added more details about how load balancing is done.

Comment: I see. Then my question is, how will the result of makespan be used? Are you reporting each machine separately or are you reporting all machines together? Why and how is the result of makespan important for **your situation**?

Comment: I want to evaluate the performance of system before and after load balancing. I want to show that the duration of implementing tasks (which I think is presented by makespan) is decreased after using load balancing algorithm, but I'm confused about how can I show this.